# How many homogeneous degree $d$ polynomials define different complex submanifolds of $\mathbb{CP}^n$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, complex-geometry, moduli-space

In $n$ (complex) variables, the degree $d$ polynomials are determined by their $\binom{n+d-1}{n-1}$ coefficients. For example, in degree $3$ in $3$ variables we have

$$f([X,Y,Z]) = a_1X^3 + a_2Y^3 + a_3Z^3 + a_4X^2Y + a_5X^2Z + a_6Y^2X $$ $$+ a_7Y^2Z + a_8Z^2Y + a_9Z^2X + a_{10}XYZ$$

and we want to consider how many parameters decide the complex structure of the zero level-set $f^{-1}(0) \subset \mathbb{CP}^2$.  Ostensibly it's $10$ because there are $10$ coefficients.

But at least one "degree of freedom" can be removed: scaling all $10$ parameters by the same factor has no effect on the zero set. I am reading that this should define an elliptic curve, so it should be decided by just *one* complex parameter $\tau$. Supposedly this can be done by a change of variables in $\mathbb{CP}^n$? Is there a general way to count the number of independent "complex structure parameters"?

Comment: so you want to count curves up to isomorphisms ? basically you need to find the dimension of the space of automorphisms of $\Bbb P^2(\Bbb C)$

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a reference on how to do that?

Comment: some proofs of the dimension of moduli spaces of curves of genus $g$ use this as an intermediate step iirc so you should start there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note, this answer is incomplete. I can't remember all the details off the top of my head. I plan to update the answer when I have access to the notes in my office.*

---

The space of degree $d$ homogeneous polynomials is $n + 1$ variables is $V\setminus\{0\}$ where $V = H^0(\mathbb{CP}^n, \mathcal{O}(d))$. As you've mentioned, rescaling the polynomial doesn't change the hypersurface, so we can consider $\mathbb{P}(V)$. Some of these polynomials will give rise to singular hypersurfaces. The set of all such polynomials is called the singular locus which we will denote by $S$. It is a Zariski closed set.

There is a right group action of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{CP}^n) = PGL(n+1, \mathbb{C})$ on $\mathbb{P}(V)$ given by $(f, A) \mapsto f\circ A$ which preserves the singular locus, i.e. if $f \in S$, then $f\circ A \in S$ for all $A \in PGL(n+1, \mathbb{C})$. So there is a right group action of $PGL(n+1, \mathbb{C})$ on $\mathbb{P}(V)\setminus S$. Let $f, g \in \mathbb{P}(V)\setminus S$ and denote the corresponding hypersurfaces by $X_f$ and $X_g$ respectively. If $f$ and $g$ are in the same orbit of this action, then there is $A \in PGL(n+1, \mathbb{C}))$ such that $g = f\circ A$. It follows that the automorphism $A : \mathbb{CP}^n \to \mathbb{CP}^n$ restricts to a biholomorphism $X_f \to X_g$. The converse is also true, i.e. if $A$ restricts to a biholomorphism $X_f \to X_g$, then $g = f\circ A$. Therefore, the orbits of $\mathbb{P}(V)\setminus S$ under the action of $PGL(n+1, \mathbb{C})$ are precisely the smooth degree $d$ hypersurfaces of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ which are biholomorphic via an automorphism of $\mathbb{CP}^n$.

A priori, two smooth degree hypersurfaces could be biholomorphic by a map which is not the restriction of an automorphism of $\mathbb{CP}^n$. I don't remember exactly what happens in this case. I think it either doesn't happen, or it does but it doesn't affect the dimension count. I will try to look this up tomorrow.

In any case, if I remember correctly, the action of $PGL(n+1, \mathbb{C})$ is free so $$\dim\, (\mathbb{P}(V)\setminus S)/PGL(n+1, \mathbb{C})$$ is an upper bound on the dimension of the moduli space of smooth degree $d$ hypersurfaces of $\mathbb{CP}^n$. As the action of $PGL(n+1, \mathbb{C})$ is free,

$$\dim\, (\mathbb{P}(V)\setminus S)/PGL(n+1, \mathbb{C}) = \dim\, (\mathbb{P}(V)\setminus S) - \dim\, PGL(n+1, \mathbb{C}).$$

As $S$ is a Zariski closed set, $\dim (\mathbb{P}(V)\setminus S) = \dim \mathbb{P}(V) = \dim V - 1 = \binom{n+d}{n} - 1$. As for the second term, $\dim PGL(n+1, \mathbb{C}) = \dim GL(n+1, \mathbb{C}) - 1 = (n+1)^2 - 1$. Therefore, the upper bound for the dimension of the moduli space is

$$\binom{n+d}{n} - (n+1)^2.$$

The moduli space of quartic K3's corresponds to $n = 3$ and $d = 4$ which gives

$$\binom{3 + 4}{3} - (3 + 1)^2 = \binom{7}{3} - 4^2 = 35 - 16 = 19.$$

The moduli space of quartic K3's is $19$-dimensional, so I suspect all of my suspicions above are correct, but I will try to confirm this tomorrow.

In the case you asked about, $n = 2$ (it is $2$ instead of $3$ because $\mathbb{CP}^n$ has $n+1$ projective coordinates) and $d = 3$, in which case the expression becomes

$$\binom{2+3}{2} - (2+1)^2 = \binom{5}{2} - 3^2 = 10 - 9 = 1.$$

So the moduli space of elliptic curves (you have to do some work to show that every elliptic curve is a degree three hypersurface of $\mathbb{CP}^2$) is one-dimensional.

A more elementary way to see this fact is to note that every elliptic curve is of the form $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is a lattice. The lattice can be chosen such that $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\tau$ where $\tau \in \mathbb{H} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \operatorname{Im}(z) > 0\}$. Two such lattices $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\tau$ and $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\tau'$ define isomorphic tori if and only if $\tau' = \frac{a\tau + b}{c\tau + d}$ where

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ 
c & d
\end{pmatrix} \in SL(2, \mathbb{Z}).$$

Therefore the moduli space of elliptic curves is $\mathbb{H}/SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$, in particular it is one-dimensional. In fact (again, if I remember correctly) it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ via the [$j$-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant).

Comment: For smooth hypersurfaces of dimension at least 3, the Picard group is generated by the restriction of the hyperplane divisor class, so that class must be preserved by any (abstract) isomorphism. That shows any abstract isomorphism must come from a projective isomorphism. For smooth curves resp. surfaces in $\mathbf P^2$ resp. $\mathbf P^3$ of degree $\neq 3$ resp. 4, the restriction of the hyperplane divisor class is a (nonzero) multiple of $K_S$, which again must be preserved. So elliptic curves and quartic $K3$s are the only interesting cases. In the latter case a _very general_ quartic

Comment: has Picard number 1, so again the argument applies, but this is more subtle than the previous cases (Noether-Lefschetz). IIRC for a general isomorphism class of elliptic curves, there are 6 projectively inequivalent curves in that class. Don't take the last statement as gospel, though!